# PL/SQL function to add +7 days to SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, function, sysdate

We're supposed to make a function that adds +7 days to the current `SYSDATE`, and also write the time and minute, however, my code only displays the date, not the time. What am I doing wrong? This is probably very easy, but I just can't figure it out, and there's not much help on the Internet either.

So far, I've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date(n IN NUMBER) 
RETURN DATE AS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'),'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') + n;
END get_date;
/
```

So when you write (the 7 is the amount of days to advance):

```
SELECT get_date(7)
FROM dual;
```

Its result is this:

```
GET_DATE(7)
----------------
09.03.2016
```

However, as you can see, the time isn't included in the result, and that's what I need in this case. Any help at all would be appreciated. I'm sure I'm just too blind to see it, but I've stared for too long on this piece of code now, I'll admit my defeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to format the result to your specifications, as in

```
--create the function  
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date(n IN NUMBER) 
RETURN DATE AS
BEGIN
  RETURN SYSDATE + n;
END get_date;

--call the function
SELECT TO_CHAR(get_date(7), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')
FROM dual;
```

Or your new requirement of no formatting outside the function

```
--create the function  
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date(n IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + n,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI');
END get_date;

--call the function
SELECT get_date(7)
FROM dual;
```

Comment: But when I add that line, I'm received with 06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state". I'm probably doing something wrong.
I add the SELECT-statement below the BEGIN, and return the "get_date". Or do I have to declare it first?

Comment: @tobulos1 I have added more detail

Comment: Oh, I see. And there's no way to format the SYSDATE from within the function? So that I could write only `SELECT get_date(7) FROM dual;` to get my result?

Comment: Thank you! That did it. So I guess I can't return time with `DATE` and have to use `VARCHAR2` instead? Plus, I had the `SYSDATE` format done before the adderation of `n`. Thank you so much, I understand it now :)

Comment: @tobulos1 The date field has a time component, it is just that the default formatting of your output isn't displaying it to you. Casting it to character lets you control the output but isn't changing the actual underlying value.

Answer (score 1):

You can decide if you want your function to return a `date` or a `varchar`; you may choose one of the following ways, depending on your need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date(n IN NUMBER) 
RETURN varchar2 AS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_char(SYSDATE  + n, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI');
END get_date;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date2(n IN NUMBER) 
RETURN date AS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_date(to_char(SYSDATE  + n, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI');
END get_date2;
/

select to_char(get_date2(1), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') from dual;

select get_date(1) from dual;
```

Answer (score -1):

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date(n IN NUMBER) 
RETURN varchar2 is

dTmp DATE:=sysdate+n;

BEGIN

RETURN to_char(dTmp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI');

END;

/

SELECT get_date(1) FROM dual;